# Python terminal emulation

Tags: python, xterm, terminal-emulator, pty

I'd like to have an xterm-compatible virtual terminal running inside a Python app.
I'll need to run ncurses-based applications inside it, feed it with user's input and read its output.

So far I've found python-vte, but it only provides a GTK+ widget (libvte has the required VtePty class, but Python bindings don't) and has an unacceptable libgtk dependency.

Is there any other way to perform a teminal emulation in Python?

Comment: So how is your python application going to display the terminal window if it does depend on a GUI library (either GTK or Qt)?

Comment: @Jan it serves a webpage where user can see the terminal and perform preset actions.

Comment: Not sure if it's for you, but I really like [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After all, I've found the [pyte](https://github.com/selectel/pyte), which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but pyte is a VTxxx emulator, not xterm. Great emulator nevertheless!

Comment: It's a linux-console emulator, but it does all what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/termemulator/) VT100 terminal emulator, also described in blog form [here](http://sivachandran.blogspot.com/2008/04/termemulator-10-released.html)? It's not an xterm emulator, but perhaps it can be leveraged for your purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not able to handle any ncurses apps, ex. aptitude

Answer (score 3):

I have been running a [Rails Tutorial](http://www.codelearn.org) site & have deployed [Gateone](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/) terminal emulator for users to execute commands. Later we devloped our own Terminal emulation. Check http://github.com/pocha/terminal-codelearn .

If you just need to execute command as a user, then probably you just need http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html