# Transparent Python call to a binary that has fancy terminal output

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script, and would like to transparently present my call to `kind cluster create` ([kubernetes-in-docker](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io)) in a terminal that runs this Python script.

I have been using Python's `subprocess.check_output` until I realized that wrapping the call like that hid a lot of output.

Is there from the Python script, to invoke `kind create cluster` as if I'd been calling it directly from the command line without invoking it from a python script?

If we can make Python do this, it would have to:

1. To stream the output
2. To get output that can updates like the animated dots
3. To get the emoji images represented as well

### `kind create cluster` running in a bash terminal

[image]

Comment: First I would try `kind create cluster | less` to see if it turns off fancy stuff when output is not a terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python terminal emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070998/python-terminal-emulation)

Answer (score 0):

I learned that I simply wanted to start using `subprocess.run(cmd)`, that gave me everything I wanted.

It allowed my `./my-python-script.py` to run code within it that resulted in everything I wanted to see, such as colors, animated dots, emojis.